# Use native node modules midi / easymidi with electron

Tags: node.js, npm, electron, midi, electron-rebuild

I am trying to use the nodemodule [easymidi](https://www.npmjs.com/package/easymidi) which depends on the [midi](https://www.npmjs.com/package/midi) module in an electron app.

When I run `npm start` an error occurs:

> Error: The module '/var/www/html/mdi/node_modules/midi/build/Release/midi.node'
>   was compiled against a different Node.js version using
>   NODE_MODULE_VERSION 46. This version of Node.js requires
>   NODE_MODULE_VERSION 73. Please try re-compiling or re-installing
>   the module (for instance, using `npm rebuild` or `npm install`)

I did try to use `electron-rebuild` as described in the [nodejs documentation](https://electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/using-native-node-modules#installing-modules-and-rebuilding-for-electron) but the error still exits.

Anyone know what to do?

Answer (score 1):

**Update (Dec 2019)**

It seems that with the latest version of *electron-builder* (version 21.2.0), you can remove *electron-rebuild* dependency and simply add a "postinstall script" like that, according to the warning of *electron-builder*:

> electron-rebuild not required if you use electron-builder (...)
>
> To ensure your native dependencies are always matched electron
>   version, simply add script `"postinstall": "electron-builder install-app-deps"` to your package.json.

---

**Original answer**

The problem occurs because *electron* uses its own *Node.js* instance, with another version.

You can see the Node ABI version used by *electron* with the command:

```
./node_modules/.bin/electron -a
```

that you can compare with your current [version](https://nodejs.org/en/download/releases/) of *Node.js*.

I solved that exactly same error with the use of *electron-rebuild*:

```
npm install --save-dev electron-rebuild
./node_modules/.bin/electron-rebuild midi
```

You could add a "postinstall" script with this command in your `package.json` to automate the process.